# Vim dadbod configuring adapters

Tags: sql-server, vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to configure the plugin dadbod (https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod) and must confess I don't know vimscript well enough to comprehend the code :(

I'm stuck on configuring the database adapters.  Irrespective of what URL I try, I just get the message

> DB: no adapter for SQL Server.

I've also tried SQLite and Postgres with the same results.

In the WIKI, there's a statement: `Supports a modern array of backends` - which makes me think I haven't configured "the backend" perhaps?  I have the jdbc SQL Server driver installed, and set a JAVA_HOME environment variable which works fine with DBeaver and with Azure Data Studio.

I haven't been able to find anything on the web about how to configure dadbod beyond the command structure.  Am I missing something obvious about how the plugin works?

Your help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Error message is coming from [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod/blob/master/autoload/db/adapter.vim#L30). This shouldn't happen if your install of vim-dadbod is complete (file `vim-dadbod/autoload/db/adapter/sqlserver.vim` is present.) Can you double check it? Or any chance that you have variable `g:db_adapter_sqlserver` set? That could interfere...

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] StackExchange for questions on Vim!

Comment: Thank you @filbranden!  Can't say I resolved it, but you gave me some insights and I now have the plugin running.  I'm now having wierd ODBC and SQLCMD errors that I'll post in Vi and Vim StackExchange as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The vim-dadbod plugin was definitely *not* installed correctly.  I did a clean install of Vim, then installed the package manager Vundle.  Following Vundle's instructions I was able to install vim-dadbod.

I'll be posting a followup later, but the issue is no longer the plugin itself!

Comment: I tend to recommend [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a more modern, well maintained alternative to Vundle. It has more features and better performance. Yet, it's very familiar to Vundle users (uses mostly the same concepts and very similar commands) so it should be very easy to transition to it!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden I'll give that one a try!  BTW: I've traced the real issue to the SQLCMD string that vim-dadbod constructs.  It's quoting all of the connection parameters with single quotes, which seems to be the problem (works if I type it out manually without the quotes).  Is that something you've had to deal with?  Cheers and thanks!

Comment: I know a bit about Vim but I don't really know much about sqlcmd or even Windows, so I don't think I can help you much here... Perhaps consider taking a look at the vim-dadbod [issue tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod/issues)? It seems there are a couple of issues there about sqlcmd or ms sql, not sure if one of them matches what you're seeing?